# trying to delete a row from database using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying remove a row from database while clicking on the remove link. but received the below error message :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

below is the code :

remove_db.php

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
//session_start();
$myusername = $_SESSION['uname'];


$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="vacation_tool"; // Database name
$tbl_name="login"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$query="select EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,ManagerName from users";

$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result) or die ("error in function_name: <br>Sql: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysql_error());

//mysql_close();
?>
<div id="bv_Text2" style="position:absolute;left:480px;top:250px;width:550px;height:16px;z-index:5;" align="left">
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr width = "100%">
<td width = "15%" align = "center"><font style="font-size:13px" color="#000000" face="Arial"><b>Employee ID</b></font></td>
<td width = "20%" align = "center"><font style="font-size:13px" color="#000000" face="Arial"><b>First Name</b></font></td>
<td width = "20%" align = "center"><font style="font-size:13px" color="#000000" face="Arial"><b>Last Name</b></font></td>
<td width = "20%" align = "center"><font style="font-size:13px" color="#000000" face="Arial"><b>Manager Name</b></font></td>

</tr>
</div>


<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"EmployeeID");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"FirstName");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"LastName");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"ManagerName");

?>
<div id="bv_Text2" style="position:absolute;left:480px;top:260px;width:144px;height:16px;z-index:6;" align="left">
<tr>
<td align = "center"><font style="font-size:13px" color="#000000" face="Arial"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td align = "center"><font style="font-size:13px" color="#000000" face="Arial"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td align = "center"><font style="font-size:13px" color="#000000" face="Arial"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<td align = "center"><font style="font-size:13px" color="#000000" face="Arial"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
<td align = "center"><font style="font-size:13px" color="#000000" face="Arial"><?php echo '<td><a href="remove.php?EmployeeID=' . $num['EmployeeID'] . '">Remove</a></td>'; ?></font></td>
</tr>
</div>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and remove.php :

```
<?php

session_start();
$myusername = $_SESSION['uname'];

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="vacation_tool"; // Database name
$tbl_name="login"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form

if (isset($_GET['EmployeeID']))
 {
 // get id value
 $EmployeeID = $_GET['EmployeeID'];

 // delete the entry

 $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE EmployeeID = $EmployeeID";

 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

 // redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: remove_user.php");
 }
 else
 // if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
 {
 echo "Error";
 }

 ?>
```

please help me.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE EmployeeID = $EmployeeID";
```

with

```
$query = sprintf("DELETE FROM users WHERE EmployeeID ='%s'",
mysql_real_escape_string($EmployeeID));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ... its not working noting happens when Clicked on remove link

Answer (score 0):

Your code states

```
<a href="remove.php?EmployeeID=' . $num['EmployeeID'] . '">Remove</a></td>'; ?></font>
```

but the `EmployeeID` is in `$f1`, not in `$num`. `$num` is not even an array.

So in addition to the error above (you should have used `$f1`), you are doing some other things not so well as you could:

- You haven't configured PHP to inform you of *all* the warnings, errors, etc. you may get.
- You are accepting a value from outside and using it in a query, exposing yourself to SQL Injection attacks (use `EmployeeID = (int)$_GET['EmployeeID']` at the very least)
- You are using `mysql_*` functions, whose usage is [discouraged](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). Use PDO or mysqli instead.
- You aren't separating your PHP code from the HTML presentation.

While perfectly possible to program without heeding any of the above hints, you will find that it is much easier, productive, and plain *more fun* to follow them. I apologise for the patronizing tone, but I found out this the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing the wrong employee ID. The employee ID is assigned to $f1, and you are using the $num['employeeID'] in the url, which should be empty.

The remove link has to be :

```
  <td align = "center"><font style="font-size:13px" color="#000000" face="Arial"><?php echo '<td><a href="remove.php?EmployeeID=' . $f1 . '">Remove</a></td>'; ?></font></td>
```

It will always be helpful doing a step by step debugging, so that you can figure it out yourself. In this case :

1. HTML view source, and look at the URL
2. print $_GET['employeeID']
3. print the delete sql

Note: mysql_query functions are deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli functions. 
Also, the $_GET has to be sanitized before directly using in any DML statement. Totally vulnerable.